# Spring boot removes/truncates values

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. When I am sending back data to a web app that has a value **false** (boolean), spring ignores to send over that property from the object.

Similarly, if I send a double value **10.0**, spring truncates it to **10**.

What configuration or which file do I need to change so that I get back my data as is?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your all object here.

Comment: Its a pretty big object, so no. You can just assume it like this: MyObject.property=10.0.